# Python: Global Variables From Within Functions + Curses

Tags: python, curses

I am being very, very confused...

Basically trying to declare a global variable pointing to a curses window so I can use a debug command however it complains `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addstr'` which implies it is not being set? Please help!

```
wDebug = None

def start(stdscr):
    curses.nocbreak()
    curses.echo()
    screenSize = stdscr.getmaxyx()

    wDebug = curses.newwin(5, screenSize[1], 0, 0);

    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLUE)

    wDebug.bkgd(curses.color_pair(1))
    wDebug.refresh()

    /* Snip */

    awaitInput(wInput)

    while 1: pass

def awaitInput(window): 
  while 1:
    msg = /* Snip */
    sendMessage(msg)

def sendMessage(msg):
  /* Snip */
  debug("Send message")

def debug(msg):
  wDebug.addstr(msg + "\n")
  wDebug.refresh()
```

Many thanks for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [global statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#global):

```
wDebug = None

def start(stdscr):
    global wDebug
    #...
    wDebug = curses.newwin(5, screenSize[1], 0, 0);
```

From the documentation:

> It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without `global`

Comment: Oh, didn't know you had to do this in Python, noob error,  thanks!

Comment: How come you can access the global variable from debug then?

Comment: @Pez: In Python, variables are assumed to be local by default. When you access a variable that doesn't get assigned to in the function, then Python will check the globals. However if you assign to any variable, Python considers that it must be a local unless you explicitly say otherwise (even if there is a global by that name). A function like `def foo(): x += 10` will raise an UnboundLocalError, even if there is a global called `x` (notice the name of the error).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I think I need to buy a book on python, just reading random tutorials means I miss out concepts like this!